# Highlight Cell in gridview after double click / Single click and store in Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to select only one cell in column of gridview but failed ,all columns are getting selected with my current code, I am weak at Jquery / Javascript.
Also I need to store selected cell value  from each column in to backend database.

please help me

following is the code for reference, which selects multiple cells in column whereas i need only one is to be get selected,

```
<script type="text/javascript"  >

         $(document).ready(function() {

             //To set the back ground color of gridview cell

             $("#<%=GridView1.UniqueID%> td").click(function() {

                 $(this).css("background-color", "red");

             });

         });
</script>
```

Current:

[image]

Needed :

[image]

Please help me

thanks in advance.

Comment: For select all the row is `$("#<%=GridView1.UniqueID%> tr")` but, to send the selected to code behind, you will need to use Ajax.

Comment: thanks Freak but I dont want to select row i need to select only one cell in each column.

Comment: Check this fiddle maybe will help you --> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QGK7m/)

Comment: This fiddle also allow me to select multiple cells in column.can we write something here so that we can select only one cell in column instead of multiple.

Comment: Thanks Freak_Droid for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code for selecting only a single cell in a column:

```
         $("#<%=GridView1.UniqueID%> tr td").click(function() {
             var indx =$(this).index(); //get index of the td
             //for each tr in the table
             $(this).parent().parent().find("tr").each(function(){
                //find the td with specific index and remove the redclass 
                $(this).find('td:eq(' + indx + ')').removeClass("redClass");
               });
             $(this).addClass('redClass');
         });
```

Forked Freak_Droid's JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EcFLH/